# Multiple search and filter Meteor & Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have simple collection  :

```
nom: {
    type: String,

},
prenom:{
    type: String,

},

categorie:{
  type: String,

},
age:{
    type:String,

    } ,

ville : {

    type : String 

    }
```

I want to find easy way to  multiple search and filter elements into a table . for exemple filter by name and age or filter by age and city . or filter by all of them 
Here is my table : 
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fOK2.png)

In my case what's the best way to make this multiple filter on mongodb and meteor without searchengine package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I tend to do my searches, so that it also finds similar results as well. So if there is a letter "A" in my result, if I search on "A" it will bring up everything with the the letter "A" until I get more specific.

Note you might want to make the search value and search keys to lowercase Because "A" != "a" and will not return anything.

I also put an int value you just incase that question came up.

```
let collection = yourCollection.find({
       "nom": {
            $regex: ".*CONDITION_VALUE.*"
       },
       "prenom": {
            $regex: ".*CONDITION_VALUE.*"
        },
        "categorie": {
            $regex: ".*CONDITION_VALUE.*"
        },
        "age": {
            $gt: minAge,
            $lt: maxAge
        },
        "ville": {
            $regex: ".*CONDITION_VALUE.*"
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

When using direct queries on **MongoDB** you can use the following examples:

The simplest way to check existence of a field is by using the [$exist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/):

```
db.collectionName.find({fieldName: {$exists: true}})
```

If you are looking for specific field value:

```
db.collectionName.find({'fieldName': 'value'})
```

Combination of [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/) and exist can look like that:

```
db.collectionName.find({ $or: [ {name: {$exists: true}}, {age: {$exists: true}} ] })
```

For multiple **$or** you can use the following query:

```
db.collectionName.find({ $or: [ {name: {$exists: true}}, {age: {$exists: true}} ] },
                       { $or: [ {age: {$exists: true}}, {city: {$exists: true}} ] })
```

Comment: Thank's for responding i don't know how $exist could help on search in to collection by multiple elements that's  in my case all columns already exist

Comment: When you search for specific name you can use:{'name': 'aaa'} etc for each field you need.